Restricted vertical scrolling in Next.js project in Android Phone
In my Next.js project, vertical scrolling is restricted on home page. But, when I load the homepage directly, the vertical scrolling happens however, when I navigate to the homepage from some other page, vertical scrolling is restricted. Any solution? Any help would be highly appreciated. And this happens only on my android phone. In PC it works fine.
Is it something about initial render concept in Next.js or in general. And this happens only on my Android phone.
I restricted vertical scrolling for the main content container. It works on navigating to the page from other page but doesn't when directly homepage is opened. Here's the homepage code:
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Logo from './components/Logo';
import ArrowAnimation from './components/ArrowAnimation';
import TextWithStyle from './components/TextWithStyle';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div 
      className="relative w-screen h-screen" 
      style={{ overflowX: 'auto', overflowY: 'hidden' }}
    >
      <Head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Sample homepage" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </Head>
      <div
        className="relative flex justify-center items-center"
        style={{
          height: '100vh',
          width: 'calc(100vh * (16 / 9))',
          minWidth: '100vw',
        }}
      >
        <img
          src="/Learn with us.png"
          alt="Learn with Us"
          className="background-image"
          style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }}
        />
        <Logo />
        <img
          src="/Aj.png"
          alt="Aj Image"
          className="absolute"
          style={{ top: '0rem', left: '9rem', width: '125px', height: '125px' }} // Adjust the size and position accordingly
        />
        <TextWithStyle />
        <div className="absolute" style={{ top: '3rem', right: '5rem' }}>
          <div className="green-neon-text">We are open</div>
        </div>
        <div className="absolute" style={{ top: '50%', right: '10rem', transform: 'translateY(-50%)' }}>
          <ArrowAnimation />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

